# html5shiv doesn't work with IE7

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer, html5shiv

I need html5 scripts to be opened by IE7.

I did input a script to call **html5shiv.js** on `<head>` script in the HTML file.

Here's my HTML code:

```
<head>
  <!--[if IE]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style_ie.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/html5shiv.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->
</head>
```

and I trying to styling a button on tag `<header>` like this:

**HTML:**

```
<header>
<input type='submit' value='LOGIN'>
</header>
```

**CSS:**

```
header input[type=submit]{
    background:url('../images/btn_login.png')repeat-x; 
    color:white;
}
```

and that's still not working, I don't know where the error is? are the error on the caller of html5shiv or in some of the syntax?

**NOTE**: no CSS class like `.Something` Allowed

Comment: Include `html5shiv` before `style_ie.css`.

Comment: @Vucko, post that as an answer—it’s the correct answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Include `html5shiv.js` **before** `style_ie.css`:

```
<head>
  <!--[if IE]>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style_ie.css" />
  <![endif]-->
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use it as a class example

```
.btn 
   {
   background:url('../images/btn_login.png')repeat-x;
   color:white;
   }
```

and use it in html as

```
<header>
<input type='submit' value='LOGIN' class='btn'>
</header>
```

Comment: Note that header and head are two different things (the latter reserved for, well, head)

Comment: Two answers by same User are not allowed, if you have the better solution then you should modified your answer. that's why `EDIT` option have been provided here.

Answer (score 0):

The Internet Explorer 7 have a buggy support for the `attribute selector`. to prevent this issue it would be goo if you can make a `class` and then apply it on input tag. I hope it will work on IE7 or even IE6.

**NEW SOLUTION**

you have to call the `html5shiv.js` and `CSS file` separately like this way.

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/html5shiv.js"></script><![endif]
-->

<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style_ie.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

**OLDER SOLUTION**

```
<input type='submit' value='LOGIN' class='myClass'>
```

**CSS would be**

```
.myClass{border:1px solid red;}
```

Comment: this will really help but using CSS class are disallowed, i must styling through header input[type=submit]{ }

Comment: Lets try this. I've specified here to check IE lower then version 9. Also please paste this script just before `</head>` tag. 

`<!--[if lt IE 9]><script type="text/javascript" src="js/html5shiv.js"></script><![endif]-->`

Answer (score -1):

IE7 not supported this attribute of HTML file so you can not use `header input[type=submit]{ }`

i need create class for ie7 and check browser if it is less than IE8 then you call that class.